# Google Maps Embed displaying incorrect address on directions

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-embed

I have just added a very simple code snippet to a client's website using the Google Maps Embed API. This displays all of the correct details, but when you click on the "Directions" link, a different address is displayed. You can see the problem on the web page here, http://www.picturesbyrob.co.uk/contact-us/

Anyone seen a problem like this before? I'm not sure if there's an underlying issue with the data or with the application.

Any pointers gratefully received. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like Westpit Lane merges into Middlecroft Drive... might just be Google incorrectly associating those coordinates with that street address.  Can you make the coordinates more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the coordinates that are passed in your direction request are https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=54.033922,-0.589114&z=7&t=m&hl=en-US&gl=US&mapclient=embed&daddr=Photographer%20in%20York%20118%20Middlecroft%20Drive%20Strensall%20York%2C%20North%20Yorkshire%20YO32%205YQ%2C%20United%20Kingdom@54.033922,-1.045047

Latitude : 54.033922
Longitude : -1.045047

Which is the address you are getting on the Google Maps when you click on the direction link.

THe coordinates for the address you are looking which is ***118 Middlecroft Drive, Strensall, York, York YO32 5YQ, UK*** are

Latitude : 54.0338228
Longitude : -1.0447040000000243

Try putting this explicitly in your request instead of geocoding it!