# Google Maps Embed: Address correct on embedded map - incorrect on directions

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-embed

Test page located at http://hmcc1.com/Contact_TEST.htm

I have tried both place_id and the actual address. ll as described in another Q&A ([Google Maps Embed displaying incorrect address on directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31542693/google-maps-embed-displaying-incorrect-address-on-directions)) returned an invalid parameter error.

Whether I use place_id or the address, when I click on Directions, the wrong address appears on the Directions page.

Here is the code in the test page:

```
<iframe width="500" height="640" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=3060+N+Kennicott+Ave,+Arlington+Heights,+IL+60004@42.132098,-87.994873&key=AIzaSyA42PChU9T0qV5kw-ikHHUv4yarQhFFo9U" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I would be grateful for any assistance. Thank you in advance.

Comment: For me it works on your testpage. The same address is shown that you can see on your testpage when clicking on directions.

Comment: I get "3050 North Kennicott Avenue, Arlington Heights, IL 60004" in the directions request (although it looks like the same building...).

Comment: @Fuzzzzel Really? Everyone else looking at it is seeing 3060 on the embedded map and 3050 on the map shown after clicking on Directions. Thanks for checking.

Comment: @geocodezip Yes, It is the same building, so anyone using the directions would (probably) still arrive at our office. I am just hoping that someone can help me find whatever error or bug is causing the discrepancy, but if not, it will not be a total disaster. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: @kathi You are right, sorry. I didn't see this as a difference at first, since 5 and 6 look pretty simlar on first sight and I was looking some completely different address that would be shown in your case ...

Comment: I would think it is a bug in the embedded API.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to leave the test page up in case someone comes up with a fix, or as @geocodezip said, maybe the API has a bug and will (someday) be fixed. For the [live page](http://hmcc1.com/Contact.htm), I ended up using the Directions mode instead. It is not exactly what I wanted, but at least it does not give the wrong address. And it does work nicely for mobile users.

I was able to use the code exactly as generated by the [Google Maps Embed Quick Start page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start):

```
<iframe width="500" height="500" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?origin=Current%20Location&destination=place_id:ChIJJ2uA_ly7D4gRRDjYtPvR62U&mode=driving&key=AIzaSyA42PChU9T0qV5kw-ikHHUv4yarQhFFo9U" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Thanks so much to all who commented!